# Как узнать, что андроид приложение запустили на эмуляторе?

Tags: java, android

Разрабатываю андроид-приложение и очень важно чтобы оно не запускалось с помощью эмуляторов. Есть возможность проверить устройство на подлинность ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На en SO предлагают `FINGERPRINT` проверять:

```
public static boolean isEmulator() {
    return Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
            || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
            || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
            || (Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
            || "google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);
}
```

Можно попробовать воспользоваться [Android emulator detector](https://github.com/framgia/android-emulator-detector)'ом.

Есть ещё [такой](https://github.com/gingo/android-emulator-detector/blob/master/EmulatorDetectorProject/EmulatorDetector/src/main/java/net/skoumal/emulatordetector/EmulatorDetector.java) вариант.

Comment: здесь проверка не только на отпечаток пальца,
Существует множество телефонов до сих пор без датчика.
Советую воть... https://github.com/framgia/android-emulator-detector

Answer (score 2):

Давным давно я использовал для этого запрос:

```
//требуется специальный пермишен
 String deviceID = 
      Settings.Secure.getString(
         context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

на эмуляторе это возвращает `NULL`, а на реальных девайсах некий `LONG`

Не знаю насколько сейчас этот способ работает